# Как stackoverflow привязать почту?

Tags: stackoverflow

Как stackoverflow привязать почту? где тут настройки что бы изменить почту или привязать?

Comment: Перейти в свой профиль (кнопка с репутацией сверху) -> править -> в столбце слева в разделе "Настройки сайта" находим "Доступ" -> кнопка "Добавить дополнительные способы входа"

Comment: оно мне перезашло под другим аккаунтом

Comment: @Starbax значит это мыло было уже привязано к другому аккаунту.